# 'abstract' property for type 'NewsArticle'

Tags: schema.org

I have a short teaser text under the headline of my news article and I wanted to ask, if I could use the property 'abstract' for it, which is a property of the type 'CreativeWork'.
In the Documentation of 'NewsArticle' it says, that I can use properties of type 'CreativeWork' https://schema.org/NewsArticle. But when I read the description of the 'abstract' property it says : "An abstract is a short description that summarizes a CreativeWork." https://schema.org/abstract. So I was not sure, if I could use this property for 'NewsArticle' or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inheritance hierarchy up to NewsArticle, as per https://schema.org/NewsArticle, is

- Thing

  - CreativeWork

    - Article

      - NewsArticle

Therefore all properties of CreativeWork are available in Article, and all properties of Article are available in NewsArticle.

---

https://schema.org/abstract says

> Used on these types
>
> - CreativeWork

https://schema.org/CreativeWork#subtypes lists Article as a subtype
https://schema.org/Article#subtypes lists NewsArticle as subtype